# How do I Post user input from javascript to python?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map of the world where a user can click on any country. I want to get the user's selected country sent to a python file where I can use it for more things.

This is the JavaScript portion of the map that deals with user selections.

```
 if (select !== null) {
      map.addInteraction(select);
      select.on('select', function(e) { 
        console.log(e);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '&nbsp;' +
        e.target.getFeatures().item(0).get('name');
        var name = e.target.getFeatures().item(0).get('name');
```

I want to get the variable "name" sent to a python program which I have written where it will be used.

I'm struggling to understand how to do this. I think I need to use JavaScript Post. This is what I have been using but I'm not sure where to put it in my HTML. I'm reading about jquery and Ajax. Should I be using those?

```
<form action="gresponse" method="post">
<input type="text" id="country" name="country"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Go" name"gobtn"/></form>
```

Comment: You have three choices: 1) Send your data to a webserver which will call the python script for you. 2) Generate a file and manually pass it to your python script. 3) Run your code in node.js and execute python from there.

Comment: @  Derek 朕會功夫 Eventually, it will all go onto google app engine. But how do I "send" the variable "name" to the python file?

Comment: "Sending a name to a python file" does not make any sense. Your JavaScript code is *client side*, while your python script is *server side*. You will need to tell the client to send the data to the server (GET, POST, ajax, etc.). The server can then execute the python code with the appropriate parameters received from the client.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp You need to make a web request to your server using Javascript. This link will show you how. You can use 3rd party tools like jQuery to simplify it for you too.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 Thanks. I was confused conceptually. So the javascript code will send the data to the server which will then run the python code with the data. And the way to get the data from javascript is to use Post, XMLHttpRequest, or ajax.

Comment: @timo That is correct! You can even directly run your python script if you are using Webapp2 on Google App Engine.

Comment: @timo By the way, XHR (`XMLHttpRequest`) is the name of the old ajax library in JS. The newer one is called `fetch` which is easier to use and compatible with promises.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) of the Javascript standard library or if you already use jQuery you could use the [`jquery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) method.