# Send JavaScript variable as input to python code

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript code declared a variable, that variable should be passed as input to python child process which is called inside JavaScript code, where python code executes its output by taking input from JavaScript variable

JavaScript code

```
    var input="onepiece";
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var python_process = spawn('python3',["/home/centos/python.py",input] );
    python_process.stderr.on('data',function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    });
```

```
import sys
input1=sys.argv[1]
print(input1)
count=0;
for i in range(0, len(input1)):
    if(input1[i] != ' '):
        count = count + 1;
print(  str(count));
```

when I execute javscript code i should get
onepiece
8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704780/how-do-i-post-user-input-from-javascript-to-python#:~:text=You%20have%20three%20choices%3A%201,and%20execute%20python%20from%20there.

Comment: What happens with your code now?

Comment: this method didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it work by connecting the stream listener to `stdout` rather than `stderr`:

```sh
python_process.stdout.on('data',function(data) {
   console.log(data.toString());
});
```